# Rails: Devise redirect to a stored location after sign in or sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm using Devise in a Rails application I'm writing, and I want to let users go back to where they were after signing in or signing up.

For example, if I have a "comments" Controller that is protected by:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Then I want users who click a "Comment Now!" button (and are therefore redirected to the new action in CommentsController) to log in and then have Devise redirect them to the new action (or wherever they were) in CommentsController, not to the generic root of the application, or to a generic after_sign_in_path.

Looking through the RDOC for Devise, I found [this method](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#stored_location_for-instance_method) that makes it look as if Devise has at least the *capability* to do something like this on its own, but I can't figure out a way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, so I've done some more experimentation, and working with Kormie's info, I've got a working solution.

From what I can determine, `before_filter authenticate_user!` does *not* save the route for returning the user. What I did was this:

First, I added an extra `before_filter` at the top of my controller

```
before_filter :store_location
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Then, I wrote the `store_location` method at the bottom of the controller

```
private

  def store_location
    session[:user_return_to] = any_old_route_path
  end
```

I don't claim this is perfect, but it works for me. (The downside for anyone else wanting to use it, is that it only supports one return path per controller. This is all I need for myself, but it is only a slight improvement over the one return path per app that I was using previously.) I would really appreciate anyone else's insights and suggestions.

Comment: I have some code that looks like this: `session[:login_redirect] = request.path unless current_user`

Comment: Note that I'm not using `:user_return_to`, because that's already used internally for devise facebook connection callbacks.  So instead to my own variable + check in a custom `after_sign_in_path_for`

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to do this:

```
# Modified from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(resource) || your_defaut_path 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Devise should do this by itself. The authenticate_user! filter also did not want to work for me when the route to the action was set via PUT method. When I have changed this to GET in routes.rb devise started to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

##### Adapted from Devise Wiki how to:

#### Redirect back to current page after sign in, sign out, sign up, update

Redirecting back to the "current page" involves saving the current url in the session and then retrieving the url from the session after the user is authenticated / signed out. This should only really be done for GET requests as the other http methods (POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE) are not idempotent and should not be repeated automatically.

To store the location for your whole application use before_action to set a callback (Use before_filter in Rails versions before 4.0).

This example assumes that you have setup devise to authenticate a class named User.

`# app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :store_user_location!, if: :storable_location?
  # The callback which stores the current location must be added
  # before you authenticate the user as `authenticate_user!` (or
  # whatever your resource is) will halt the filter chain
  # and redirect before the location can be stored.
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # To redirect to the stored location after the user signs
  # signs in you would override the after_sign_in_path_for method:
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    # *My note, not wiki*: you may need a fall back as
    # stored_location_for can return nil. I've added root_path
    stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || root_path
  end
    
  private
    # Its important that the location is NOT stored if:
    # - The request method is not GET (non idempotent)
    # - The request is handled by a Devise controller
    #   such as Devise::SessionsController as that could
    #   cause an infinite redirect loop.
    # - The request is an Ajax request as this can lead
    #   to very unexpected behaviour.
    def storable_location?
      request.get? && is_navigational_format? &&
      !devise_controller? && !request.xhr? 
    end
    
    def store_user_location!
      # :user is the scope we are authenticating
      store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
    end
end
```

##### Reference

[Devise How To: Redirect back to current page after sign in, sign out, sign up, update](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-%5BRedirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update%5D)

Comment: Great answer, thanks for reviving an old thread.  I ended up changing the `before_action` in my application because I didn't want the stored redirect to happen from all landing pages. In my case I put the `before_action` in the specific controllers and added `, :only => [ :page_name ]` to make sure it only ran for specific pages in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think by default Devise saves the route but you may be usinging

```
sign_in @user
```

this should redirect you

```
sign_in_and_redirect(@user) #assuming you are sigining in that resource
```

Comment: Using

`before filter :sign_in_and_redirect(@user)`

doesn't work. The error given indicates that arguments can't be passed. (i.e. "Unexpected character '('") How can I get the equivalent behavior of the before_filter using this code?

Comment: I've been messing around with it and here's what i've come up with. First, devise is storing the first URL you hit inside of `redirect_location_for(:user)` assuming that "User" is your model. Second, if you add a `redirect_to redirect_location_for(:user)` into whatever your signing controller is, this should all work like magic

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [after_sign_in_path_for](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers%3aafter_sign_in_path_for)? If you define that method in your ApplicationController  it should override the default implementation on a per controller basis.