# Devise: how to store a particular location, not necessarily the last location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm wondering if I'm asking too much of Devise. I'd like to allow a visitor to fill out a form and then but then be required to sign up when they press the "submit" button.  That's the easy part.  My problem is that once the user is redirected to the sign up form and they fill it out, I can't get them redirected back to the original form so that *that* form can be submitted (but now with the user ID).

I've played around with the "after_sign_in_path_for(resource)" method in the application controller, but my problem is that after signup, the request.referer isn't the original form, it's the signup form.  I thought about using a before_filter :store_location callback, but then I realized that it'll store the most recent location, which is the url for the signup form.

How do I set up devise that original form as the correct location to render after sign up?

P.S. This question comes from a related one, located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578892/modifying-devise-with-after-sign-in-path-forresource#comment15319436_11578892).

Comment: I hope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255283/how-do-i-make-devise-redirect-to-a-stored-location-after-sign-in-or-sign-up?rq=1   hel you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this make 2 method in ApplicationController which saves 
the current url to the session, and another that redirects to the stored 
url (which should have a default in case it can't find it). Then, in 
pages which i want to bookmark for returning to (you might not want 
someone to get sent back to some pages), then save the url.

EG in application.rb

```
   def store_location
      session['saved_location'] = request.request_uri
   end

   def redirect_to_back_or_default(default)
     if session['saved_location'].nil?
            redirect_to default
     else
       redirect_to session['return-to']
       session['saved_location'] = nil
     end
   end
```

Then, in a page that you want the user to be able to go back to:

Then, just call
redirect_to_back_or_default('enter your chosen default url here, depending on context') 
in after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope) to send someone back.