# Devise gem - how to stay on current page after login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to login in a popup. 
Is it possible to reload the current page after successful login (instead of going to the root path)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application_controller add following:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  your_path
end
```

this will override devise method. Also you maybe will find useful this method:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  your_path
end
```

Comment: But what should I put in place of "your_path"? I want to reload the current page I'm on

Comment: try to put something like :back or "back" this will redirect your on the same page

Comment: hmhm, try something like *request.referer*, also look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330588/redirect-loop-with-devise-after-sign-in-path-for . Hope this is will help you!