# Devise redirect back to the original location after sign in or sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here I'm using Devise Gem for authentication. If someone want to open page without login then it redirect to sign_in page and after signed in it back to the page which user try to open.
I use [Redirect loop with Devise after_sign_in_path_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330588/redirect-loop-with-devise-after-sign-in-path-for) link for my problem but it does not work for me.

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   params[:next] || super 
 end
```

It doesn't redirect back me to the page which I want to open.
for example: If I want to open "127.0.0.1:3000/post/2/edit", it doest not back to this page after signed in.

Answer (score 50):

The best resource to seek is the official repo/wiki/issues, and then SO. The answer you found is out of date.

Here is the answer:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

Just add the following in ApplicationController **for versions devise > 3.2.1:**

```
    # This example assumes that you have setup devise to authenticate a class named User.
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :store_user_location!, if: :storable_location?
  # The callback which stores the current location must be added before you authenticate the user 
  # as `authenticate_user!` (or whatever your resource is) will halt the filter chain and redirect 
  # before the location can be stored.
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  private
    # Its important that the location is NOT stored if:
    # - The request method is not GET (non idempotent)
    # - The request is handled by a Devise controller such as Devise::SessionsController as that could cause an 
    #    infinite redirect loop.
    # - The request is an Ajax request as this can lead to very unexpected behaviour.
    def storable_location?
      request.get? && is_navigational_format? && !devise_controller? && !request.xhr? 
    end

    def store_user_location!
      # :user is the scope we are authenticating
      store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
    end
end
```

And then to redirect after signing in, you have to override this method:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || super
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Billy for your response.. while using this code, it always redirect me to root_path(home page)and not in specific page which I opened before login

Comment: @rubydev, do you use Firefox and addon to disable referrer? Also use debug tool, say add `<%= debug session =>` in template, or rails console to check what happened.

Comment: Thanks @Billy, its working now, Only one change here is that I change after_filter to before_filter

Comment: @rubydev, nice to know it's working though the solution is still a bit weird. Maybe other code in your app affected that. I used the original solution without any problem.

Comment: This solution works and it's very clean, but keep in mind that it might store POST requests as long as API requests for JSON format.

Comment: Save my life, I don't know why they don't give a more available example!

Comment: It didn't work for me until I turned off the `remote=true` option in my `simple_form`

Comment: Is there a recommended place to put `after_sign_in_path_for`? I placed it under `protected` section of application_controller, and it seems to work great. But just wanted to check that it's a good idea?

Answer (score 31):

You don't need all this code. [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/e303de97569fcc2c338ac2ad7908aabf54076b2c/lib/devise/failure_app.rb#L193) (as the latest versions) already saves the location for you.

Just use this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_url
end
```

This will redirect user to the latest omniauth.source, or the stored_location and is last case, the root url.

I thought I was required to create that method, but Devise already does it.

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: But notice should access request.env['omniauth.origin'] before sign-in user.

Answer (score 8):

As pointed out in the official documentation, the [simpler solution](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update#a-simpler-solution) would be to simply add this to your `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base


private

# If your model is called User
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session["user_return_to"] || root_path
end
```

Important Note (Which I also overlooked) is that for this to work you will need to call `authenticate_user!` method, available by default in Devise, in your controller's `before_action:`. This will call `store_location_for` available [out of the box in Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/store_location.rb), and the rest is handled by the above code in the `application_controller.rb`, thus eliminating the need to rewrite code to save requesting url.

Comment: This solution works whether with `remote: true` as well as without, while the @Billy Chan's solution only works without.

Comment: I am trying to do same but in my case “sign in” call is AJAX request. Is there way to achieve it with Ajax call?

Answer (score 7):

As of [Devise 4](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update#devise-40), it worked seamlessly for me:

> Devise automatically redirects on sign in and sign up as long as you
>   store the location of the current page using devise's
>   `store_location_for(resource)`. To do this, edit your
>   `ApplicationController` in
>   `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`. Add:
>
> ```
> # saves the location before loading each page so we can return to the
> # right page. If we're on a devise page, we don't want to store that as the
> # place to return to (for example, we don't want to return to the sign in page
> # after signing in), which is what the :unless prevents
> before_filter :store_current_location, :unless => :devise_controller?
>
> private
>   # override the devise helper to store the current location so we can
>   # redirect to it after loggin in or out. This override makes signing in
>   # and signing up work automatically.
>   def store_current_location
>     store_location_for(:user, request.url)
>   end
> ```
>
> Add the following to the `ApplicationController` to make sign out
>   redirect:
>
> ```
> private
>   # override the devise method for where to go after signing out because theirs
>   # always goes to the root path. Because devise uses a session variable and
>   # the session is destroyed on log out, we need to use request.referrer
>   # root_path is there as a backup
>   def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
>     request.referrer || root_path
>   end
> ```

Comment: I am trying to do same but in my case “sign in” call is AJAX request. Is there way to achieve it with Ajax call?

Comment: Small correction. Instead of "before_filter" you should use "before_action". Otherwise works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Some of the other solutions here may not work if your login form has its own page, as opposed to, e.g., a login form in the header of every page. After logging in, the user needs to go back *two* pages, not just one.

Devise has a nice How To on [Redirecting back to the current page after sign in, sign out, update](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update), from which the code below comes.

Storing the original URL in the session is the best option. In addition to solving the above problem of going back *two* pages, "Many browsers do not send [the `request.referer`] header. Therefore the only robust cross-browser way to implement this functionality is by using the session."

When storing URLs in the session, it's important not to store the URL for any POST, PUT, or DELETE request, nor any XHR request, i.e. nothing to which the user can't actually be redirected.

Note that after signing out, the user's session is destroyed, so the stored URL is gone. In this case, the user can be sent back to `request.referer`. This seems acceptable since most websites have a sign out link on every page, so returning to the referrer will actually work.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :store_user_location!, if: :storable_location?
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  private
    def storable_location?
      request.get? && is_navigational_format? && !devise_controller? && !request.xhr? 
    end

    def store_user_location!
      store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
    end

   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
     stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || super
   end

   def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
     request.referrer || super
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I has the same doubt and found this, try it too

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  session.fetch 'user_return_to', admin_root_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`gem 'devise', '~> 4.4.0'`

1. Create sessions_controller.rb: `class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController`
2. Add the following (modifying the regex if your login url isn't /users)

   ```
   def before_login
     session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/
   end

   def after_login
     session[:previous_url] || root_path
   end
   ```

Notice that this does not work if you've got /users/dashboard or other locations under /users. Might want to get more specific with the regex.

Comment: I am trying to do same but in my case “sign in” call is AJAX request. Is there way to achieve it with Ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to define new methods in Devise 4.4.3. Just call method `DeviseController#after_sign_in_path_for` directly.

Code like this:

```
  class YourController < DeviseController

    # ... 
    if manager.valid_password? params[:manager][:password]
      sign_in manager

      # call this method directly , if your controller extends DeviseController
      redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(manager), notice: 'welcome!'
    end
```

Also, if you are using your customized login method and using DeviseController, you must NOT use this code:

```
# this method will login automatically, in most cases this method is 
# useless and misleading.  
prepend_before_action :allow_params_authentication!, only: :create
```