# Redirect to previous page after login with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to implement this functionality using Devise, but I can't get it to do anything other than redirect to the homepage.

I need to put something in my `after_sign_in_path_for` method.

I've tried:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_url
  super
end
```

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944159/devise-redirect-back-to-the-original-location-after-sign-in-or-sign-up) and pretty much every other post regarding this on SO without any luck.  Apparently Devise stores the previous locations by default, but I've tried doing it myself:

```
after_filter :store_location

def store_location
  # store last url as long as it isn't a /users path
  session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
end
```

I've done dozens of different combinations of the above and answers in other questions.  Why don't any of these work?  I don't even get errors or anything, it basically just ignores my code and redirects to the homepage no matter what I do.

Comment: Have you checked the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update)?

Comment: @NicNilov Yes, I've tried pretty every piece of code in there.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `request.referer` with this

```
redirect_to request.referer
```

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-ruby-on-rails) could also provide more insight