# Ruby on Rails "undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using "Devise" and I want to call the current_user.email in the students dashboard. But I keep getting the same "undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass" error.

students/index.html.erb

```
<div class="student-index-header">
    <br><%= current_user.email %></br>
  <div class="student-index-header-text">
    <a class="student-index-header-text-sign-out" href="<%= destroy_user_session_path %>">Sign-out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

student.rb

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name , :age, :description
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :tutor
  has_one :student

 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Comment: `current_user` is not defined. Are you sure you've loaded it? This might require being logged in, but you're not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise returns **nil** for `current_user` if your user is not logged in.

Try this:

```
<%= current_user.email if user_signed_in? %>
```

You should also add this line to your controller if the page requires the user to be signed in (this would make the if clause above redundant, as we've already checked whether the user is logged in in the controller):

```
authenticate_user! unless user_signed_in?
```

You also might want to redirect your user back to this page after they login. To learn how to do that, check [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944159/devise-redirect-back-to-the-original-location-after-sign-in-or-sign-up)

Comment: Ser Friendzone, Thanks so much that did help me and fixed the problem.

Comment: Happy to help Blake!