# How to redirect back to a link after logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My application has a function, if a user saved a comment, an email with a link will be sent and if a link is clicked, a comment is opened, if the user already logged-in.
If user didn't log-in yet, then a log-in page is opened.

But I don't know how can I write the code for the redirection to comment page(link) after logged-in...

Means:

If user logged-in => click the link => comment page opened (working)

If user not logged-in => log-in page opened => user logged-in (till here working) => comment page(link) opened (not working).
Currently a message was shown "You need to log in or sign up before continuing." but no log-in page is opened.

If I change the link `<%= link_to 'Go to this project', ranks_url %>`, then I can open the log-in page and after that the correct page.

```
<%= link_to 'Go to your comment', registered_comments_url(@comment) %>
```

**comments_controller**

```
before_action :store_user_location!, if: :storable_location?
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def storable_location?
    request.get? && is_navigational_format? && !devise_controller? && !request.xhr?
  end

  def store_user_location!
      # :user is the scope we are authenticating
    store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || super
  end
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Devise redirect back to the original location after sign in or sign up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944159/devise-redirect-back-to-the-original-location-after-sign-in-or-sign-up)

Comment: Thanks for the information! I already tried [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update), but I can not go to log-in page and a message "You need to log in or sign up before continuing." is shown... I tried with other link `<%= link_to 'Go to the overview', comments_url %>` and this link redirected to log-in page and after that index page.  I could not find any solution yet... Do you have any idea?

Comment: I modified my question contents so that it's hopefully clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use "is_navigational_format?" like below,

```
def storable_location?
      request.get? && is_navigational_format? && !devise_controller? && !request.xhr?
    end
```

and if you have a link with id like "/comments/anytask.123", then "is_navigational_format?" can not judge ".123" as a format.

So I needed to add below routes and solved!!!

```
get 'comments/anytask.:id' => 'comments#anytask', as: :comments_anytask
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in numerous ways.

First of all, I don't agree with that before_action, simply because in that method you check if the user is signed in, this can be achieved using `before_action :authenticate_user!` from Devise.

Clean way:

If you just use the `:authenticate_user!` callback this will force a redirect to sign-in page, after the sign in you will be redirected to the desired page by default (the comment show page in your case).

**Note:** This may or may not work if you have specific logic in `after_sign_in_path_for` method (from Devise) in `application_controller` (I'm sure in your case this should work).

Comment: Thanks! As you mentioned, I changed `before_action :authenticate_user!` and eliminated `before_action :comment_link`.

Comment: But this problem is still not solved... how should I modify my code?

Comment: @frankyorg where it redirects you after you sign in?

Comment: To the linked location `<%= link_to 'Go to your comment', registered_comments_url(@comment) %>`

Comment: @frankyorg and that is not the page you want to go? From your description you say you want to:  "if user not logged-in => log-in page opened => user logged-in (till here working) => comment page(link) opened (not working)." If you want we can do a Skype call and you can show me the behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind suggestion. Currently I'm straggling, because if I have a link for index, I can go to index page after login, but if I have a link for edit, I can not go to login page (A page with a message " You need to log in or sign up before continuing.")... If you have any ideas, please let me know.